# How to write raw data directly to usb printer on Linux?

Tags: linux, qt, printing

I'm developing app with qt4 (c++) for Linux platform. When I'm using QTextDocument::drawContext method(), sometimes (not always) printer is printing some junks and wasting a lot of paper. I think it can be related with printer driver. This is Oki MicroLine 3390 eco printer. This printer is emulating EPSON LQ driver.

I have tested few epson drivers but that did not help at all. I cannot fix this issue so I have started looking for some alternative solution - write directly to device.

I'm looking for info:

1. How to write raw data (formatted text) to usb dot matrix printer?
2. is any one know how to fix printing issue?

Comment: this doesn't looks like software developer problem. This is problem with you printer driver. Did you try print test page or from other software? How do you print that (if it's programing problem show some code)?

Comment: Correct, from other software there is same issue. Maybe write data directly to device would solve issue? Question is how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

any write command will do print on device /dev/usb/lp0

test it # cat [file] > /dev/usb/lp0

Answer (score 0):

Try to send reset sequence before printing process:

```
[ write_2_printer("\x1b\x40");]
```